# How to update a Kendo NumericTextBox in a razor page with correct formatting?

Tags: razor-pages, kendo-asp.net-mvc

I am trying to update Kendo NumericTextBoxes via the datamodel in my razor page. I have a field

```
@(Html.Kendo().NumericTextBoxFor(m => m.DataModel.FieldName)
                .Format("{0:C}"))
```

and then try to update it with

```
$('#DataModel_FieldName').val(value).change()
```

The problem is when I update the code as shown above, it does not show the updated value on the front end unless I click the NumericTextBox.

It seems it may be holding two different values or something like that but I am expecting it to show the updated value without needing to click the NumericTextBox (This is how the Kendo TextBox works). I have tried numerous solutions and nothing seems to work so any help or ideas would be greatly appreciated, thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got it to work by using jQuery to get the Kendo NumericTextBox's data and then setting the value like this:

```
let kendoNumericTextBox = $('#DataModel_FieldName').data('kendoNumericTextBox') 
kendoNumericTextBox.value(value)
```